# how to append string if kwargs key pass

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

do I have a better pythonic way to write the following code? What I want to do is if function passes key argument as 'a', then append some string to value else just pass empty string

```
def testFunc(**kwargs):
    b = '' if not 'a' in kwargs else '//{}'.format(kwargs['a'])
    print(b)
testFunc()
testFunc(a='this')
```

Comment: Why exactly are you accepting kwargs if you're only interested in the `a` parameter? Any reason why you can't make `a` a normal parameter? Some context would help.

Comment: it is just a simple code, I have more logic in my function actually

Comment: `... if 'a' not in kwargs` else ...`, but otherwise there is nothing to improve here.

Answer (score -1):

Use [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) to get 'a' if it is given in the keyword args. And if it's not present, the default return value is `''`:

```
b = kwargs.get('a', '')
if b:
    b = '//{}'.format(b)
```

The first assignment gets `'a'` from the dict and assigns it to `b`. Then if `b` is non-empty (the `''`), then reformat with the `'//'`.

Edit: I assume is that if 'a' is not provided in kwargs but is empty (`''`), then `b` will also be empty and not just '//'. In your current code, if `'a'` is provided and is empty, then `b` becomes `'//'`. If you want empty or missing `a`'s to both result in the empty string for `b`, then use my version. Otherwise, your version is fine - but change to `... if 'a' not in kwargs else ...` as MartinP put in the comments.

Comment: The original code produces `b=''` rather than `b='//'` if `a` isn't provided.

Comment: yes, if a does not provide, I like a pass b as empty string, if a exist, then b = '//' + variable from kwargs

Comment: Your new revision still has different behavior if the caller provides `a=''`.

Comment: @user2357112 The expectation (I assume) is that if 'a' is not provided or empty, then `b` will also be empty and not just `'//'`.